# How to sort array by array of indices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I had a simple array of numbers `arr = [4, 2, 7, 5]`

I did some calculations with it, swapped some values and now I have two arrays:

The array itself `arr = [4, 7, 2, 5]`

And the array of indices for this array `indices = [0, 2, 1, 3]`

Each number indicates where the value of the array is in (value with index 1 swapped with value with index 2).

Having these two arrays, how could I return `arr` to it's initial state? So that `arr[1]` would be swapped with `arr[2]` as the `indices` array indicates.

P.S. I have numpy available to simplify things with arrays.

Comment: What is the expected output, please be explicit

Comment: The expected output is the original unchanged and unsorted array

Comment: Are you trying to go from `[4, 7, 2, 5]` to `[4, 2, 7, 5]` using indices?

Comment: @Chris let me check that

Comment: @DarrylG Yes, exactly

Comment: `np.array([4, 7, 2, 5])[indices]` -> `array([4, 2, 7, 5])` using Numpy indexing.

Answer (score 1):

```py
arr = [4,7,2,5]
indices = [0,2,1,3]
arr2 = [arr[i] for i in indices]
print(arr2)
```

Comment: This sometimes doesn't give correct answers. Input: `indices = [2, 1, 4, 3, 0]` and `arr=[3, 1, 4, 1, 3]` gives me `[4 1 3 1 3]` but should give `[3 1 3 1 4]`

Comment: @developer1 -- the issue could be your definition of indices is different from what is commonly meant.  The usual meaning is the list comprehension in this answer.  Did you have a different meaning?

Comment: @developer1 I don't understand how it would be `[3,1,3,1,4]`. Did you by chance mean to apply rearrangement with the indices twice? Or reversing the order? Because doing it twice or reversing the order of the array, seems to be giving the output that you're expecting. Can you show more examples of arrays and indices and the corresponding outputs that you're expecting from them?

Comment: Sorting by using this method `[x for _, x in sorted(zip(Y, X))]` described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list did solve it correctly provided in comments by Chris

Comment: Sorry, maybe you misunderstood or I didn't explain it correctly, but `indices = [2, 1, 4, 3, 0]` and `arr=[3, 1, 4, 1, 3]` should be sorted so that `indices` in the end would be `[0,1,2,3,4]` and `arr` accordingly.

Comment: @developer1 I see. Well, yea in such case the link in Chris's comment is probably the most efficient way to do it. Another way, perhaps not as efficient, is to use this: `list(list(zip(*sorted(zip(indices,arr))))[1])`