# sorting nested list based on another lis

Tags: python, sorting

```
a = [[1,3,45,6,78,9],[2,6,5,88,3,4],[44,66,2,4,77,12]]
b = [4,6,3]
```

These are two lists in python, now each element in the first list a corresponds to the element in the list b with the same index. i.e a[0]:4,a[1]:6,a[2]:3 and so on.

Now I want to sort list b and then print the respective values corresponding to list a.
I cannot use a dictionary because it gives an error that a is not hashable.
 My desired output is:

```
x = [[44,66,2,4,77,12], [1,3,45,6,78,9], [2,6,5,88,3,4]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting list based on values from another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list)

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```py
a = [[1,3,45,6,78,9],[2,6,5,88,3,4],[44,66,2,4,77,12]]
b = [4,6,3]

c = sorted([[b[i],a[i]] for i in range(len(a))])
x = [i[1] for i in c]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done on a single line like:

```
a = [[1,3,45,6,78,9],[2,6,5,88,3,4],[44,66,2,4,77,12]]
b = [4,6,3]

c = [el for _, el in sorted(zip(b, a))]
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[[44, 66, 2, 4, 77, 12], [1, 3, 45, 6, 78, 9], [2, 6, 5, 88, 3, 4]]
```

(If the values in `b` are not unique, it will sort by first element in the corresponding the values from `a`)

Answer (score -1):

There is no issue using a dictionary as long as you avoid using any list as a key. In this case, you could use `b` for keys and `a` for values. For example,

```
d = dict(zip(b,a))
print([d[k] for k in sorted(d)])
```