# How do I sort a list containing data with another list containing the first lists indexes in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

As part of my homework  I have two files. One has a list of participants with numbers in front of them. The other file has a list of finishing numbers correlated to the first list, for example:

1. John
2. Kate
3. Jimmy

The second file will have:
3
1
2

So the results of the race would be

1. Jimmy
2. John
3. Kate.

How do I sort the first list corresponding to the second list's indexes? I can't seem to get the  result index right and I can't figure out how to get it in a relation with the initial participant list.

```py
with open("participants.txt") as f:
    participants = []
    for line in f:
        participants.append(line.strip().split(". "))
    for i in range(len(participants)):   
        try:
            participants[i][0] = int(participants[i][0])
        except:
            continue
with open("participantresults.txt") as d:
    participantresults = []
    for line in d:
        participantresults.append(line.strip("\n"))
    for i in range(len(participantresults)):   
        osalejate_tulemused[i] = int(osalejate_tulemused[i])

resultindex = []
for n in osalejate_tulemused:
    resultindex.append(participantresults.index(n)) #faulty

result = []
for n in range(len(resultindex)):
  ..... 



with open("result.txt", "w") as f:
   #write the list here later.
```

Comment: Is this a [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) question? Also, what specific part of the task are you struggling to understand? Please [edit] and tell us.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting list according to corresponding values from a parallel list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-according-to-corresponding-values-from-a-parallel-list)

Comment: Tried it before submitting this post and I discovered it a useful solution, if it would be that the numbers were the indexes that it sorts by.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your participants into dictionary so that the key is their identifier from the first file. Then you can point to these by the second file:

```
with open("participants.txt") as f:
    participants = []
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        participants.append(line.strip().split(". "))

participants = {index: name for index, name in participants}

with open("participantresults.txt") as d:
    order = []
    for line in d:
        order.extend(line.strip().split(" "))

with open("tulemus.txt", "w") as fw:
    for i, p_index in enumerate(order):
        fw.write(f"{i+1}. {participants[p_index]}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a dictionary for this - just a list **providing** the values associated with the names (in participants.txt) start at 1 and increase with no intervals.

It's also assumed that the values in participantresults.txt are as per the question - i.e., all on one line

```
participants = ['']

with open("participants.txt") as p:
    for line in map(str.strip, p):
        if line: # ignore blank lines
            # the leading number in this file is irrelevant
            _, name = line.split(maxsplit=1)
            participants.append(name)

with open("participantresults.txt") as p, open("result.txt", "w") as r:
    for i, j in enumerate(map(int, next(p).split()), 1):
        print(f'{i}. {participants[j]}', file=r)
```

The result.txt will look like:

```
1. Jimmy
2. John
3. Kate
```