# List of cols to list of rows

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of lists, where the lists represent columns.  All the lists are the same length and the number of lists is variable.  I want to convert the lists of columns into lists of rows.  It doesn't have to end in a dictionary a matrix is perfect; however, I can't use `numpy`.

For example: The setup looks something like this

```
>>> A = [ 1 ,  2 ,  3 ,  4 ,  5 ,  6]
>>> B = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
>>> C = ["J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O"]
>>> d = {"One": A, "Two": B, "Three": C}
```

do magic here and get the following

```
[(1, 'A', 'J'), (2, 'B', 'K'), (3, 'C', 'L'), (4, 'D', 'M'), (5, 'E', 'N'), (6, 'F', 'O')]
```

Notice the first element in the cols are now in a row. Now I can get this by doing

```
>>> zip(d["One"], d["Two"], d["Three"])
```

but this would only work if the number of dictionary entries was constant.  How can I do this if the number of dictionary entries was variable? Hope I'm clear.

Comment: Does the order of the keys in the dictionary matter?  I mean, are the keys really `"One"`, `"Two"`, `"Three"`, and you want to use them in the usual order?

Comment: @Sven Marnach No order does not matter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A Transpose/Unzip Function in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/a-transpose-unzip-function-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the documentation for [Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).  By putting a `*` in front of an iterable that is an argument to a function, the function will be called with the elements from that iterable as its arguments.  For example `zip(*['ab', 'cd', 'ef'])` would become `zip('ab', 'cd', 'ef')`.

Using this method you can generate your zipped list of an arbitrarily sized dictionary, but note that because dictionaries are unordered you will need to provide a separate list to use as an order for the resulting column groups, for example:

```
>>> A = [ 1 ,  2 ,  3 ,  4 ,  5 ,  6]
>>> B = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
>>> C = ["J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O"]
>>> d = {"One": A, "Two": B, "Three": C}
>>> order = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
>>> zip(*[d[k] for k in order])
[(1, 'A', 'J'), (2, 'B', 'K'), (3, 'C', 'L'), (4, 'D', 'M'), (5, 'E', 'N'), (6, 'F', 'O')]
```

If the column order does not matter, you can use [Sven's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9181020/505154) which is very concise but the tuple order will be arbitrary.

Answer (score 4):

If the order of the dictionary items does not matter, you can do

```
zip(*d.values())
```

to get the desired result.