# python column split

Tags: python, numpy

I have a python array in the format:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Is there a way for me to break it up into columns to give:

```
[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [python list of lists transpose without zip(*m) thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/python-list-of-lists-transpose-without-zipm-thing)

Comment: possible duplicate of [A Transpose/Unzip Function in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/a-transpose-unzip-function-in-python)

Comment: Is this really an array as specified by NumPy? Or an object of type `array` as created by the `array` module? Because what you've described looks instead like a `list`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think NumPy is good for this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> my_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> x = np.array(my_list)
>>> np.transpose(x).tolist()
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: There is _no need_ for external libraries for something this simple.

Comment: That doesn't mean they aren't a good thing to use. There can be many good things to use, and knowing many of them is a good thing.

Comment: The OP mentioned array, so it makes sense to bring up numpy.

Answer (score 4):

```
In [85]: [list(x) for x in zip(*[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])]
Out[85]: [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

If you want list of tuples you can use:

```
In [86]: zip(*[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
Out[86]: [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Comment: The list comprehension is only necessary if you actually need the inner sequences to be lists.

Comment: But in above case it seems to be lists, however if we don't put list(x) we will end up getting tuple which user doesn't want

Comment: He shows them as lists, that doesn't mean he actually needs them to be lists.

Comment: You don't need list comprehension for 2nd case:                  zip(*[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

Comment: Another way: `map(lambda *x: list(x), *[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])`