# How to unzip a list of tuples into individual lists?

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples `l = [(1,2), (3,4), (8,9)]`. How can I, succinctly and Pythonically, unzip this list into two independent lists, to get `[ [1, 3, 8], [2, 4, 9] ]`?

In other words, how do I get the inverse of what [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) does?

Comment: `zip` is basically it's own inverse.  It's pretty cute like that. :)

Comment: `zip` is *not* it's own inverse. It is close though. A function that is its own inverse is called an *involution*. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19343/1959808) uses `zip` to define an involution.

Comment: If you want to sort the values of X by the values of Y and return two separate lists after , you can do : `y,x= map(list,zip(*sorted(zip(y, x))))`

Answer (score 534, accepted):

Use `zip(*list)`:

```
>>> l = [(1,2), (3,4), (8,9)]
>>> list(zip(*l))
[(1, 3, 8), (2, 4, 9)]
```

The [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) pairs up the elements from all inputs, starting with the first values, then the second, etc. By using `*l` you [apply all tuples in `l` as *separate arguments* to the `zip()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901), so `zip()` pairs up `1` with `3` with `8` first, then `2` with `4` and `9`. Those happen to correspond nicely with the columns, or the *transposition* of `l`.

`zip()` produces tuples; if you must have mutable list objects, just `map()` the tuples to lists or use a list comprehension to produce a list of lists:

```
map(list, zip(*l))          # keep it a generator
[list(t) for t in zip(*l)]  # consume the zip generator into a list of lists
```

Comment: Clever.... perhaps too clever. Anyone reading this without surrounding comments will scratch their head for some time.

Comment: @speedplane: then put it in a function and name it `transpose()`. It's no more unreadable than many `numpy` or `pandas` operations; it's a bit specialist but does the job really well.

Comment: In Python3, this creates a zip object.    `>>> l = [(1,2), (3,4), (8,9)]`  `>>> zip(*l)`  `<zip at 0x1042d8c48>` which can be viewed with a list comprehension `>>> [ii for ii in zip(*l)]`  `[(1, 3, 8), (2, 4, 9)]`.

Comment: @amath: There is no need for a list comprehension. Just use `list()`: `list(zip(*l))`, much faster.

Comment: **Beware**: `a, b = zip(*list)` will fail if `list` is empty so you'll have to treat empty as a special case. You won't get back two empty tuples - of course how could you? If this case can occur then it's much better to use a list comprehension instead.

Comment: @IanGoldby: or use exception handling. `try: a, b = zip(*list)`, `except ValueError: a, b = (), ()`.

Comment: ```x  , y = map(list, zip(*l)
```

Comment: Is this memory efficient if l is a very long list?

Comment: @Visionscaper in that case iterate over `zip(*long_list)` directly; `list(zip(*long_list))` would have to allocate enough memory for a new list plus a tuple per pair (iteration can potentially get away with reusing the same memoised tuple object).

Comment: NB: you don't have to use list `x,y = tuple(zip(*((x,y) for x,y,_ in tuples))))`

Comment: @CervEd: neither is needed. `x, y = zip(*((x, y) for x, y, _ in tuples))` would also work. As would `x, y = zip(*(xy for *xy, _ in tuples))`.

Comment: In case you have **nested lists** of (x,y) pairs and want to separate them as list of lists of x and y, you just need to iterate the previous procedure for each nested list: `x, y = zip(*[ zip(*[ (x, y) for a in range(3) ]) for b in range(5)])` (or `map(list, zip(*[ map(list, zip(*[ (x, y) for a in range(3) ]) )  for b in range(5)]) )` if you want it as list of lists).

Answer (score 93):

If you want a list of lists:

```
>>> [list(t) for t in zip(*l)]
[[1, 3, 8], [2, 4, 9]]
```

If a list of tuples is OK:

```
>>> zip(*l)
[(1, 3, 8), (2, 4, 9)]
```

Comment: I think `map(list, zip(*l))` is quite nice in Python 2.x. Anyway, +1 for option of list of lists :)

Comment: I prefer list comprehension above `map` :)

Comment: @dav1d Interesting, do you have reference?

Comment: @dav1d -- That's not true.  The speed of map vs. list-comp is entirely problem dependent (You'll see different timings from different people for different problems on SO relatively frequently).  `map` + `lambda` is usually slower though ...  The nice thing about a list-comp is that it's the same in py2k and py3k.

Comment: @dav1d -- Here's an older, but classic [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map) which shows the opposite (and the results still hold for me using python2.7 on OS-X)

Comment: Ok, I should rephrase, a `LC` is mostly faster than `map`. And no I don't have a reference, but I made a few tests back in 2.6 time and redid them with 2.7 and map was always slower.

Comment: @mgilson interesting, in my tests the LC was always faster.

Comment: Great this also works when l itself is a tuple, 2-dimension tuple I mean