# How to separate iterables by tab instead of element in Python

Tags: python, iteration

I'm trying to build a very simple program to turn data that looks like this:

```
ID  Freq
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   1
6   1
7   1
8   1
9   1
10  1
11  2
12  2
13  2
14  3
15  3
16  3
17  4
18  5
19  5
20  5
21  5
22  5
23  5
24  5
```

into two lists in python. This is the for loop I've written:

```
newlist = []
ID = []

for line in f:
    if len(line.strip())>0:
        l=line.strip().split("\t")
        for i in l[1]:
            newlist+=[i]
        for i in l[0]:
            ID+=[i]

print(newlist)
print(ID)
```

The problem is it outputs each digit in the multiple digit numbers (e.g. 10 and over in the variable "ID") as a separate element.

e.g:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '3', '1', '4', '1', '5', '1', '6', '1', '7', '1', '8', '1', '9', '2', '0', '2', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '2', '4']
```

Instead of this:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24']
```

I've looked at the unzip function for tuples, but this is different as the data are not tuples. Rather, the issue is getting python to read each two-digit number as one iterable, rather than each digit as an iterable.

Comment: What exact output do you want ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to unzip a list of tuples into individual lists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974474/how-to-unzip-a-list-of-tuples-into-individual-lists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need those interior `for` loops. Just add the items of `l` directly. Also, use `append` instead of `+=`.

```
newlist = []
ID = []

for line in f:
    if len(line.strip())>0:
        l=line.strip().split("\t")
        newList.append(l[1])
        ID.append(l[0])
```

Comment: Thanks. Why append instead of +=?

Comment: Every time you do `some_list += [item]`, it creates a brand new copy of `some_list`, adds the item to it, and updates the variable with that value. This operation runs in O(n) time - the longer the list is, the longer it takes. `append` does not create a new copy of the list. It takes O(1) time - no matter how long the list is, it takes the same amount of time.

Comment: That makes sense. However, if I were to use an internal for loop (e.g. using a counter) is there a simple syntax change to  make it count each data point rather than each digit?

Comment: @Kevin: uhm, `+=` augmented assignment does **not** create a new copy of `some_list`. The whole *point* of adding augmented assignments to the language was to allow for in-place editing of mutables.

Comment: @Kevin: `newList += [l[i]]` is exactly equivalent to `newList.append(l[i])`.