# 2 lists of lists. Sort both according to len of lists of one

Tags: python, sorting

I have two lists:

```
X=[[1,2,3],[5,5],[1]]
Y=[[2,4],[1,4,6,6],[1,3]]
```

There is a one-one correspondence between the elements of lists X and Y. I want to sort the elements of X by the length of items, and at the same time the items of Y be sorted in the correct position by the new indices of X's items.

The result should be:

```
X=[[1],[5,5],[1,2,3]]
Y=[[1,3],[1,4,6,6],[2,4]]
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. I wasn't aware of that policy. I will edit this asap with what I tried, and where I am stuck.

Comment: You should take a look at [sort()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html): `list.sort( key=len )` will order items in `list` by their length.

Answer (score 6):

> There is a one-one correspondence between the elements of lists X and Y

This suggests that you should [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) the lists together before you do anything else to them.

```
>>> zippedLists = zip(X, Y)
```

`zippedLists` will be a list of tuples containing corresponding elements from `X` and `Y`:

```
>>> list(zippedLists)
[([1, 2, 3], [2, 4]), ([5, 5], [1, 4, 6, 6]), ([1], [1, 3])]
```

Now you can rearrange the tuples according to the length of the first element, using the `key` argument to [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> sortedZippedLists = sorted(zippedLists, key=lambda x: len(x[0]))
>>> list(sortedZippedLists)
[([1], [1, 3]), ([5, 5], [1, 4, 6, 6]), ([1, 2, 3], [2, 4])]
```

And then [unzip the lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974474/how-to-unzip-a-list-of-tuples-into-individual-lists), if you need to.

```
>>> sortedX, sortedY = zip(*sortedZippedLists)
>>> list(sortedX)
[[1], [5, 5], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> list(sortedY)
[[1, 3], [1, 4, 6, 6], [2, 4]]
```

Or, as a single expression:

```
zip(*sorted(zip(X,Y), key=lambda x: len(x[0])))
```

Comment: Really, sometimes I don't understand how thing goes around here, OP didn't provide any try he already committed in his question, we asked him to post tries so we can assist him as per the well famous expression that I've encountered many times: "SO..is not a code writing service"...I already had the same solution cooked and ready to be posted...but thought that I should wait for OP to edit his Q...now I see people upvoting here .. kinda confusing ..:P .. If I knew it will get upvoted, I would've posted .. :(

Comment: @IronFist Yep, same here. I had the same solution ready as well but was waiting for the OP to edit his question.

Answer (score 0):

## A Baroque Solution

```
[Y[i] for i in list(zip(*sorted(zip(X, range(len(X))), key=lambda x:len(x[0]))))[1]]
```

#### Does It Works?

```
In [6]: X
Out[6]: [[1, 2, 3], [5, 5], [1]]

In [7]: Y
Out[7]: [[2, 4], [1, 4, 6, 6], [1, 3]]

In [8]: [Y[i] for i in list(zip(*sorted(zip(X, range(len(X))), key=lambda x:len(x[0]))))[1]]
Out[8]: [[1, 3], [1, 4, 6, 6], [2, 4]]
```