# Convert tuple elements into separate strings

Tags: string, tuples, python-3.5

I have a dictionary which contains tuples, which in turn, contain strings & integers. I want to convert them to series of strings separated by comma.

```
new = [('POU5F1', 13), ('BICD1', 11), ('VEGFA', 10)]
links = [', '.join([t[0] for t in new])]
print(links)
```

How can I convert this to the following format:

```
 print(links)
 ['POU5F1', 'BICD1', 'VEGFA']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974474/how-to-unzip-a-list-of-tuples-into-individual-lists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unzip a list of tuples into individual lists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974474/how-to-unzip-a-list-of-tuples-into-individual-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this code can help:

```
new = [('POU5F1', 13), ('BICD1', 11), ('VEGFA', 10)]
links = []

for i in new:
    links.append(i[0])

print(links)
```