# How to split an array of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, sub-array

I have this array that contains some other arrays in Python, but I need only the first elements of each mini array inside the main array. Is there some method to do that?

Example:

```
array = [['a','1'], ['b','2'], ['c','3'], ['d','4'], ['e','5']]
```

I need the letters in one row:

```
'a'
'b'
'c'
'd'
'e'
```

And the numbers in another:

```
'1'
'2'
'3'
'4'
'5'
```

can You help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unzip a list of tuples into individual lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974474/how-to-unzip-a-list-of-tuples-into-individual-lists)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` to separate letters from numbers and `map` to convert the tuples returned by `zip` to lists:

```
array = [['a','1'], ['b','2'], ['c','3'], ['d','4'], ['e','5']]

letters, numbers = map(list, zip(*array))

print(letters)
print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use comprehension. a[0] means first item in a list

```
[a[0] for a in array]

Result:
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: welc. glad to help!

Comment: Hey, hi again!
Do you know how add an '\n' to each element?

Comment: a[0]+'\n'. this will add a new line

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
letters,numbers = tuple(zip(*array))
```