# How can I sort two lists identically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have two Python lists as below:

```
 list1 = ['River (OTH)', 'River (N)', 'River']
 list2 = ['River (OTH) sales', 'River (N) sales', 'River sales']
```

And I sorted the above list with the code:

```
list1.sort()   
list2.sort()
```

After sorting I get the list as:

```
list1 = ['River', 'River (N)', 'River (OTH)']
list2 = ['River (OTH) sales', 'River (N) sales', 'River sales']
```

I need the `list2` also to be sorted like:

```
list2 = ['River sales', 'River (N) sales', 'River (OTH) sales']
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Applying `sort` on the second list do not provide the output you wrote but : `['River (N) sales', 'River (OTH) sales', 'River sales']`. If you are looking to reversed order, call  `sorted(list, reverse=True)`

Answer (score 2):

1. This is assuming both lists are originally co-ordered.

You could use the function `zip` in order to "glue" the two lists together, than sort this new list according to the elements of `list1`, and then separate them back. More easy to show:

```py
list1=['River (OTH)','River (N)','River']
list2=['River (OTH) sales','River (N) sales','River sales']

zip_list = list(zip(list1, list2))
#  zip_list = [('River (OTH)', 'River (OTH) sales'), ('River (N)', 'River (N) sales'), ('River', 'River sales')]

zip_list.sort(key=lambda elem: elem[0])
#  zip_list = [('River', 'River sales'), ('River (N)', 'River (N) sales'), ('River (OTH)', 'River (OTH) sales')]

sorted_list1 = [elem[0] for elem in zip_list]
#  sorted_list1 = ['River', 'River (N)', 'River (OTH)']

sorted_list2 = [elem[1] for elem in zip_list]
#  sorted_list2 = ['River sales', 'River (N) sales', 'River (OTH) sales']
```

- Note that you can get the separated lists back more efficiently according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12974504/6045800) answer. (`sorted_list1, sorted_list2 = [list(t) for t in zip(*zip_list)]`)

In case you want it reversed, simply add `reverse=True` to the `sort()` call.

Another interesting solution could be using `enumerate` to "remember" the changes occured by indices:

```py
indexed_list1 = list(enumerate(list1))
#  [(0, 'River (OTH)'), (1, 'River (N)'), (2, 'River')]

indexed_list1.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
#  [(2, 'River'), (1, 'River (N)'), (0, 'River (OTH)')]

indices, sorted_list1 = (list(l) for l in zip(*indexed_list1))
#  sorted_list1 = ['River', 'River (N)', 'River (OTH)']
#  indices = [2, 1, 0]

sorted_list2 = [list2[i] for i in indices]
#  ['River sales', 'River (N) sales', 'River (OTH) sales']
```

---

2. If the lists are not co-ordered, but the only distinction is the `sales` word (or any other word for that matter) in the end, you could simply do:

```py
import re

list2.sort(key=lambda s: re.sub("\s*sales$", "", s))
# list2 = ['River sales', 'River (N) sales', 'River (OTH) sales']
```

This will sort the list while ignoring the ending word `sales`. I used regex to allow any number of spaces. The use of `rstrip` might change other parts of the string.

---

3. Otherwise, this is too specific and requires a specific solution