# How can I 'unzip' a list in Python?

Tags: python

Let's say I have two lists:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Based on `a`, I want to remove the value at that index for both lists if it's even. I thought of using a zip:

```
c = [i for i in zip(a,b) if i[0] % 2 == 0]
```

But now how can I turn `[(2, 6), (4, 8)]` back into two separate lists? As:

```
a = [2, 4]
b = [6, 8]
```

Obviously I can use two list comprehensions, but I was curious if it's possible to do that in one line with some built-in python function. Something like:

```
a, b = somefunc(c)
```

Comment: @wim I'm so dumb, I never knew that was a thing!! Thanks for showing me the light!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` again

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]
a, b = zip(*[i for i in zip(a,b) if i[0] % 2 == 0])
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12974504/1048186) for more details on why `zip(*...)` undoes `zip(...)`.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!