# Splitting a list of sequences into two lists efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A Transpose/Unzip Function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/a-transpose-unzip-function-in-python)

I have a list of sequences, each sequence has two items. I would like to turn this into two lists.

```
catalog = [('abc', '123'), ('foo', '456'), ('bar', '789'), ('test', '1337')]
```

Right now I'm just doing this:

```
names = []
vals = []

for product in catalog:
        names.append(product[0])
        vals.append(product[1])

print (names)
print (vals)
```

Which outputs two lists, and works just fine:

```
['abc', 'foo', 'bar', 'test']
['123', '456', '789', '1337']
```

Is there a neater, more 'pythonic' way of doing this? Or should I stick with what I have? Any corrections or feedback on programming style is welcome, I'm new and trying to learn best practices.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
>>> catalog = [('abc', '123'), ('foo', '456'), ('bar', '789'), ('test', '1337')]
>>> names, vals = zip(*catalog)
>>> names
('abc', 'foo', 'bar', 'test')
>>> vals
('123', '456', '789', '1337')
```

The `*catalog` syntax here is called [Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), and `zip(*catalog)` translates into the call `zip(catalog[0], catalog[1], catalog[2], ...)`.

The [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) builtin function groups iterables by indices, so when you pass a bunch of two-element tuples as above, you get a two-element list of tuples where the first tuple contains the first element of each tuple from `catalog`, and the second tuple contains the second element from each tuple from `catalog`.

In a quick timeit test the `zip()` version outperforms a looping approach when I tested with 1,000,000 pairs:

```
In [1]: catalog = [(i, i+1) for i in range(1000000)]

In [2]: def with_zip():
   ...:     return zip(*catalog)
   ...: 

In [3]: def without_zip():
   ...:     names, vals = [], []
   ...:     for name, val in catalog:
   ...:         names.append(name)
   ...:         vals.append(val)
   ...:     return names, vals
   ...: 

In [4]: %timeit with_zip()
1 loops, best of 3: 176 ms per loop

In [5]: %timeit without_zip()
1 loops, best of 3: 250 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! I'd never heard of this function before. I'm linking to the documentation for this function, for future readers. 

http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: It's terse and simple, but is it performant? In any other language creating a zillion parameters would be horrible.

Comment: @MarkRansom -- I've wondered about that on occasion as well...

Comment: Hmm.  My results are different -- I get `zip` ~ 490 ms, `without_zip` ~ 326 ms, and a manual `[c[0] for c in catalog]/[c[1] etc.]` only 205.  [`itemgetter` seems comparable to the listcomp.]  I tend to ingore factors of order unity, though, and so I'd probably use the `zip` myself regardless of speed.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, use this:

```
lst = [('abc', '123'), ('foo', '456'), ('bar', '789'), ('test', '1337')]
tup1, tup2 = zip(*lst)
```

The above will return a pair of *tuples* with the elements. If you need *lists*, then use this:

```
lst = [('abc', '123'), ('foo', '456'), ('bar', '789'), ('test', '1337')]
lst1, lst2 = map(list, zip(*lst))
```

Comment: A tuple will do just fine for my use, but thanks for being thorough!