# Converting one column in CSV to a paragraph in html page with python

Tags: python, csv

I have a code that converts CSV to HTML directly so that it looks like a table in html webpage format. However, I want it to take the first column and then convert that first column into a div with the text in the first column reading like a normal paragraph. So if:

1   5
 2   6
3  7
4  8  
then the div would be horizontally

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

so in a way i'ts some sort of transpose matrix...

The document will eventually be about 100 rows by 4 columns. I'd like to eventually pull each column and make them paragraphs after the other.

here is what the code is to turn the csv in to an html table

```
import sys
import csv

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print "Usage: csvToTable.py csv_file html_file"
    exit(1)

reader = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1]))


htmlfile = open(sys.argv[2],"w")


colnum = 0


htmlfile.write('<div style="margin-left:220px;">')

for column in reader: 
    if colnum == 0:
        htmlfile.write('<p>') 
        for row in column:
            htmlfile.write ( row ) 
        htmlfile.write('</p>') 
    else:      
        rownum = 1
        if colnum % 2 == 0:
            htmlfile.write('<p class="color1">')
        else:
            htmlfile.write('<p class="color2">')


htmlfile.write('</div>')
exit(0)
```

and this is what i have reformatted in the hopes of making paragraphs

```
htmlfile.write('<div style=" position: absolute; margin-

left:520px; top:100px;">')

for column in reader: 
    if colnum == 0:
        htmlfile.write('<p>') 
        for row in column:
            htmlfile.write ( row ) 
        htmlfile.write('</p>') 

htmlfile.write('</div>')
exit(0)
```

but of course i'ts not working!! I've only been learning python for about 3 days so I don't really know how to d this yet even after pouring over books and websites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the CSV file as a list of tuples using [csv. reader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) function. Then, you can use the [zip function to transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/a-transpose-unzip-function-in-python) the data. Once the rows and columns are interchanged, you can iterate through the resultant rows joining them to form a paragraph and each row as a div.