# Iterating through nested list

Tags: python, list, loops

How do i create a function to iterate my list in this manner. 
Seems simply but im stuck...

```
    myList= [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

    def name(myList):
        somework..

    newList = [[1,4,7]. [ 2,5,8], [3,6,9]]
```

Comment: Are you asking for a way to transpose your list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A Transpose/Unzip Function in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/a-transpose-unzip-function-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

```
In [3]: zip(*myList)
Out[3]: [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

if you specifically want list

```
In [4]: [list(x) for x in zip(*myList)]
Out[4]: [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

for more details on `zip` function look at [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: can you produce a function that acts the same?

Comment: @BAI -- prior to editing, there was an unnecessary list-comp in here.  It's since been removed.

Answer (score 2):

[`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) is what you want + argument unpacking.  It's awesome.  I like to think of it as python's builtin transpose.

```
newList = zip(*myList)
```

This will actually give you an iterable (python3.x) or `list` (python2.x) of `tuple`, but that's good enough for most purposes.