# Make scatter plot from set of points in tuples

Tags: python, matplotlib, set

I have set of points in tuples, like this:

```
>>> s
set([(209, 147),
     (220, 177),
     (222, 181),
     (225, 185),
     (288, 173),
     (211, 155),
     (222, 182)])
```

What is the right way to do scatter plot of this set?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can do:

```
x,y = zip(*s)
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

Or even in an "one-liner":

```
plt.scatter(*zip(*s))
```

[`zip()` can be used to pack and unpack arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19339/832621) and when you call using `method(*list_or_tuple)`, each element in the list or tuple is passed as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = []; y=[]
for point in s:
   x.append(point[0])
   y.append(point[1])
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use NumPy arrays you can use:

```
data = np.array(list(s))
```

First transform `s` to a list and than to a NumPy array.

Now you have a *list op points*, to get a lists of x's and y's you can use:

```
xs = data.transpose()[0]   # or xs = data.T[0] or  xs = data[:,0]
ys = data.transpose()[1]
```

And make a plot with:

```
plt.plot(xs, ys, 'ro')
```