# python how to unzip elements in a list, zip(*) doesn't work for me

Tags: python, zip

I wrote this program, where I need to make a list of names, with last names alphabetized, and first names in front of it.
This is what I did so far:

```
firstnames = ['good', 'bad', 'tall', 'big']
lastnames = ['boy', 'girl', 'guy', 'man']
list3 = [a + b for a, b in zip(firstnames, lastnames)]
l3 = sorted(list3)
n = len(l3)
l4 = zip(*[l3])
print l3
print l4
```

the zip* makes the elements into tuples, but how do I separate the elements again, and join them in a different order?

Comment: what version of Python are you using?

Comment: What output would you like? The code that you have *seems* like you want to just have another copy of the list, which you can accomplish using `l4 = l3[:]` or a host of other methods.

Comment: How could you separate the items again? `l3` is `['badgirl', 'bigman', 'goodboy', 'tallguy']`: you've concatenated the strings together. How could the code know to separate `goodboy` into `good` and `boy`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A Transpose/Unzip Function in Python (inverse of zip)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/a-transpose-unzip-function-in-python-inverse-of-zip)

Comment: oh sorry I'm using 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've done `a+b` you can't separate them. You've concatenated the strings together, and there's nothing in the result to indicate what part of the string is the firstname and what part the lastname.

Do your sorting on the tuples that come from `zip`:

```
print sorted(zip(firstnames, lastnames), key = lambda pair: pair[1])
```

One they're sorted, you can concatenate the strings.

Also, be aware that you could just zip them in the other order, then they'll sort on the lastname without needing to specify `key`:

```
print [b + a for a, b in sorted(zip(lastnames, firstnames))]
```

Comment: `key = lambda pair: pair[1]` means it sort list of tuples-pairs using first element in pair? for `[('c', -1), ('a', 1), ('b': 0)]`  becomes = `[('a', 1), ('b': 0), ('c', -1)]` Am I correct?

Comment: This helped yes, I should sort after.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: almost. `pair[1]` is the *second* element in the pair, `pair[0]` would be the first.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use zip once:

```
ans = ['%s %s' % (first, last) for (first, last) in zip(firstnames, sorted(lastnames))]
```