# How can I convert this tuple of tuples into a count of its elements?

Tags: python, python-2.7, count, tuples

I have this `tuple` of tuples:

```
TupleOfTuples = (('Venue1', 'Name1'), ('Venue1', 'Name2'), 
                 ('Venue2', 'Name3'), ('Venue3', 'Name4'), 
                 ('Venue3', 'Name5'), ('Venue3', 'Name6'))
```

I want to convert it to get a result like this:

```
Output = (('Venue1', 2), ('Venue2', 1), ('Venue3', 3))
```

In this case, `Output` contains `('Venue1', 2)`, for example, where `2` is the number of times `'Venue1'` occurred in `TupleOfTuples`.

I tried using `len()` to count the number of occurrences, but it does not work given that `TupleOfTuples` is not a single tuple but a tuple of tuples.

How can this be done in Python2.7?

Comment: Simple looping and keeping count will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count how many occurrences you have:

```
from collections import Counter

Output = Counter(t[0] for t in TupleOfTuples).items()
```

A `Counter()` is a dictionary where keys are mapped to counts; by passing in a generator expression it will do the counting for you. Because it is a dictionary subclass, `dict.items()` can then be used to produce a list of `(key, count)` tuples.

This does produce a *list*; simply call `tuple()` on that if you insist on having a tuple here.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> TupleOfTuples = ( ('Venue1', 'Name1'), ('Venue1', 'Name2'), ('Venue2', 'Name3'), ('Venue3', 'Name4'), ('Venue3', 'Name5'), ('Venue3', 'Name6') )
>>> Counter(t[0] for t in TupleOfTuples).items()
[('Venue1', 2), ('Venue3', 3), ('Venue2', 1)]
```

Comment: Marked as answer. Best and only answer:)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this quickly and easily using `zip(*TupleOfTuples)[n]` to get a sequence of all elements to be counted (where `n` is the index of the element in each `TupleOfTuples` tuple to count; in this case, `0`), then iterating through the result to get a count for each unique element.

Here's what it looks like:

```
TupleOfElements = zip(*TupleOfTuples)[0]
Output = tuple((e, TupleOfElements.count(e)) for e in set(TupleOfElements))
```

I'll explain what's going on:

`zip(*TupleOfTuples)[0]` takes your input sequence and [transposes it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/a-transpose-unzip-function-in-python-inverse-of-zip). We want the *zero'th* element from each `TupleOfTuples` element, so we take `[0]` from the result. We assign that sequence to `TupleOfElements`. (If you wanted to count the *Name** elements instead, for instance, you would use `zip(*TupleOfTuples)[1]`.)

`tuple((e, TupleOfElements.count(e)) for e in set(TupleOfElements))` creates the `Output` you want by iterating through `TupleOfElements` and returning an element-count pair for each unique element: `TupleOfElements` contains *all `TupleOfTuples` elements in the correct quantity*, so we can use `TupleOfElements.count(uniqueElement)` will tell us how many occurrences of `uniqueElement` there are. We don't need or want to recheck any specific element more than once, though, so we iterate through [`set(TupleOfElements)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), which will contain exactly one of each element present. We assign the result to `Output`, and we're done!

- Note: This will return `Output` as a `tuple`. If you want it as a `list`, replace the `tuple(..)` in the second line with `[..]`, keeping the contents the same.
- On performance: This code seems to run considerably faster than Martijn's very good solution using `collections.Counter`-- around 3.5x faster for the example `TupleOfTuples` given, and about 1.25x faster in a much larger but much simpler 88,888-element test I made up to satisfy my own curiosity-- I should imagine because it replaces the dictionary-creation step with a tuple and iterator. It may not be *quite* as elegant, but I'm a bit proud of it all the same.