# How to find a string that is repeated in a csv file and formatting the result in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a file in .csv with contains ht:

```
1,winter
2,autumn
3,winter
4,spring
5,summer
6,autumn
7,autumn
8,summer
9,spring
10,spring
```

I need to parse this file to generate one containing :

```
winter = 1,3
autumn = 2,6,7
spring = 4,9,10
summer = 5,8
```

I find this post [How to print count of occourance of some string in the same CSV file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585297/how-to-print-count-of-occourance-of-some-string-in-the-same-csv-file-using-pytho) but I could not adapt to what I want.

I appreciate any help or guidance to address this concern.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an empty dict and open csv and read each row.
while reading each row check if `row[1]` in dict.
Else add it to the dict, create a list with the value `row[0]`.
If that is already present append the value to the dict.
Something like this.

```
import csv
try :
    fr = open("mycsv.csv")
except:
    print "Couldn't open the file"
reader = csv.reader(fr)
base={}
for row in reader :
     if len(row) > 0:
            if row[1] in base: #Check if that season is in dict.
                    base[row[1]].append(row[0]) # If so add the number to the list already there.
            else:
                    base[row[1]]=[row[0]] # Else create new list and add the number
print base
```

It gives output something like this.
`{'autumn': ['2', '6', '7'], 'spring': ['4', '9', '10'], 'winter': ['1', '3'], 'summer': ['5', '8']}`

Comment: That result I wanted. I will work to get the format I need. Thank you very much for your help.