# How do I plot a list of tuples with matplotlib?

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, tuples

I have a list of tuples with the tuples being (`minTemp`, `averageTemp`, `maxTemp`).
I would like to plot a line graph of each of these elements in the tuple, on the same matplotlib figure.

How can this be done?

Comment: There is not any time information? What would be on the horizontal axis?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the array of the min, average and max temperature respectively, the zip functionis good [as you can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/a-transpose-unzip-function-in-python-inverse-of-zip) .

```
from pylab import plot, title, xlabel, ylabel, savefig, legend, array

values = [(3, 4, 5), (7, 8, 9), (2, 3, 4)]
days = array([24, 25, 26])

for temp in zip(*values):
    plot(days, array(temp))
title('Temperature at december')
xlabel('Days of december')
ylabel('Temperature')
legend(['min', 'avg', 'max'], loc='lower center')
savefig("temperature_at_christmas.pdf")
```

[image]

You can import these functions from numpy and matplotlib modules as well, and you can alter the layout (the color in the example) as follows:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, title, xlabel, ylabel, savefig, legend
from numpy import array

values = [(3, 4, 5), (5, 8, 9), (2, 3, 5), (3, 5, 6)]
days = array([24, 25, 26, 27])

min_temp, avg_temp, max_temp = zip(*values)
temperature_with_colors_and_labels = (
    (min_temp, 'green', 'min'),
    (avg_temp, 'grey', 'avg'),
    (max_temp, 'orange', 'max'),
)

for temp, color, label in temperature_with_colors_and_labels:
    plot(days, array(temp), color=color, label=label)
title('Temperature at december (last decade)')
xlabel('Days of december')
ylabel('Temperature (Celsius)')
legend()
savefig("temperature_at_christmas.png")
```

[image]

You can find the keyword arguments of the plot function on the [matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) or in the docstring of the function.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to change the colours of the three lines? I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: @Samuel There is a version now with given colors in the answer. Would you accept this answer if it is answers your question?

Comment: Thank's to your answer, I understood that the canonical way to plot a list of tuples is like this: `XY=[(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]; x_only, y_only = zip(*XY); plt.plot(x_only, y_only)`

Comment: Perhaps not canonical, but the shortest way, I think. zip(*XY) works as if you would call zip with the elements of the XY lists as positional arguments, as follows:
`zip((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))`
Here is [the documentation of the zip command](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).