# pandas sort with capital letters

Tags: sorting, pandas

Running this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['ADc','Abc','AEc'],columns = ['Test'],index=[0,1,2])
df.sort(columns=['Test'],axis=0, ascending=False,inplace=True)
```

Returns a dataframe column ordered as: `[Abc, AEc, ADc]`. 
ADc should be before AEc, what's going on?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me, I can reproduce this on pandas 0.16.0, numpy 1.9.1 python 3.4.3 64-bit

Comment: Confirming the bug with older pandas `0.14.0`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think that's a pandas bug. It seems to be just the way python sorting algorithm works with mixed cased letters (being case sensitive) - [look here](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/sorting)

Because when you do:

```
In [1]: l1 = ['ADc','Abc','AEc']
In [2]: l1.sort(reverse=True)
In [3]: l1
Out[3]: ['Abc', 'AEc', 'ADc']
```

So, since apparently one cannot control the sorting algorithm using the pandas sort method, just use a lower cased version of that column for the sorting and drop it later on:

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame(['ADc','Abc','AEc'], columns=['Test'], index=[0,1,2])
In [5]: df['test'] = df['Test'].str.lower()
In [6]: df.sort(columns=['test'], axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=True)
In [7]: df.drop('test', axis=1, inplace=True)
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
  Test
1  Abc
0  ADc
2  AEc
```

Note: If you want the column sorted alphabetically, the `ascending` argument must be set to `True`

**EDIT:**

As [DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm) suggested, to avoid creating a new helper column, you can do:

```
df = df.loc[df["Test"].str.lower().order().index]
```

**UPDATE:**

As pointed out by [weatherfrog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1668646/weatherfrog), for newer versions of pandas the correct method is `.sort_values()`. So the above one-liner becomes:

```
df = df.loc[df["Test"].str.lower().sort_values().index]
```

Comment: Yeah, this is Python behaviour.  Alternatively, you could do something like `df.loc[df["Test"].str.lower().order().index]`, to avoid creating a temporary column.  The OP will still have to decide how "AbC" and "ABc" should be ordered relative to one another.

Comment: The above one liner no longer works with newer versions of Pandas because `Series.order()` is now `Series.sort_values()`. So this transforms to `df.loc[df["Test"].str.lower().sort_values().index]`.

Answer (score 4):

Using **`DataFrame.sort_values`** with **`key`** argument since `pandas >= 1.1.0`:

We can now pass a custom function of the string or any other custom key in the sort_values method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['ADc','Abc','AEc'],columns = ['Test'],index=[0,1,2])
print(df)

  Test
0  ADc
1  Abc
2  AEc
```

```
df.sort_values(by="Test", key=lambda x: x.str.lower())

  Test
1  Abc
0  ADc
2  AEc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to sort multiple columns using `reindex`, extended from @Zero's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30522143/1072869). We want to sort the example dataframe first by the second column (`SORT_INDEX1`), then the first (`SORT_INDEX2`). This example sorts the secondary column (`SORT_INDEX2`) using a case-insensitive sort, then the primary column (`SORT_INDEX1`) using the default case-sensitive sort.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['q', '1'],['a', '1'],['B', '1'],['C', '1'],
                   ['q', '0'],['a', '0'],['B', '0'],['C', '0']])

SORT_INDEX1 = 1
SORT_INDEX2 = 0

# Cannot change sorting algorithm used internally by pandas.
df_default = df.sort_values(by=[SORT_INDEX1, SORT_INDEX2])

# Use tuple of (index, value to sort by) to get a list of sorted indices, obtained through unzipping.
df_new = df.reindex(list(zip(*sorted(zip(df.index, df[SORT_INDEX2]), key=lambda t: t[1].lower())))[0])
           .sort_values(by=SORT_INDEX1)

print('Original dataframe:')
print(df)

print('Default case-sensitive sort:')
print(df_default)

print('Case-insensitive sort:')
print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
Original dataframe:
   0  1
0  q  1
1  a  1
2  B  1
3  C  1
4  q  0
5  a  0
6  B  0
7  C  0
Default case-sensitive sort:
   0  1
6  B  0
7  C  0
5  a  0
4  q  0
2  B  1
3  C  1
1  a  1
0  q  1
Case-insensitive sort:
   0  1
5  a  0
6  B  0
7  C  0
4  q  0
1  a  1
2  B  1
3  C  1
0  q  1
```

([More info on unzipping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19343/1072869))

**EDIT:** Apologies, the second sort does not work properly for larger datasets. The secondary column's order is not preserved. This method will work fine for sorting by one column, but I still need to find a reliable and concise way to sort 2 columns.