# In python, can I lazily generate copies of an iterator using tee?

Tags: python, iterator, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to create an iterator which lazily creates (potentially infinitely many) copies of an iterator. Is this possible?

I know I can create any fixed finite number of copies by simply doing

```
from itertools import tee
iter_copies = tee(my_iter, n=10)
```

but this breaks down if you don't know n ahead of time or if n is infinite.

I would usually try something along the lines of

```
from itertools import tee

def inf_tee(my_iter):
    while True:
        yield tee(my_iter)[1]
```

But the documentation states that after using tee on an iterator the original iterator can no longer be used, so this won't work.

---

In case you're interested in the application: the idea is to create a lazy [`unzip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/a-transpose-unzip-function-in-python-inverse-of-zip?lq=1) function, potentially for use in [pytoolz](https://toolz.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). My current implementation can handle a finite number of infinite iterators (which is better than plain `zip(*seq)`), but not an infinite number of infinite iterators. Here's the [pull request](https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz/pull/241) if you're interested in the details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is only barely touched upon in a single example near the bottom of the Python 2 `itertools` documentation, but `itertools.tee` supports copying:

```
import itertools, copy

def infinite_copies(some_iterable):
    master, copy1 = itertools.tee(some_iterable)
    yield copy1
    while True:
        yield copy.copy(master)
```

The example in the documentation actually uses the `__copy__` magic method, which is the hook used to customize `copy.copy` behavior. (Apparently `tee.__copy__` was added as part of a [copyable iterators project](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0323/) that didn't go anywhere.)

Note that this will require storing every element ever produced by the original iterator, which can get very expensive. There is no way to avoid this cost.

Comment: Great! Strangely that example (the `tee_lookahead` right?) is in the 2.7 documentation but not the 3.4 documentation. Do you know if there's a good reason for that?

Comment: @dshepherd: No idea. The method is still there in Python 3, but the example isn't.