# How can I sum (make totals) on multiple object attributes with one loop pass?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to sum multiple attributes at a time in a single loop:

```
class Some(object):
    def __init__(self, acounter, bcounter):
        self.acounter = acounter
        self.bcounter = bcounter

someList = [Some(x, x) for x in range(10)]
```

Can I do something simpler and faster than it?

```
atotal = sum([x.acounter for x in someList])
btotal = sum([x.bcounter for x in someList])
```

Comment: Your biggest saving would be to not build a list for `sum`, just use a gen-exp: `sum(x.acounter for x in someList)`

Comment: it looks that I cannot sum all at once (a, b) and get result.

Answer (score 6):

First off - `sum` doesn't need a list - you can use a generator expression instead:

```
atotal = sum(x.acounter for x in someList)
```

You could write a helper function to do the search of the list once but look up each attribute in turn per item, eg:

```
def multisum(iterable, *attributes, **kwargs):
    sums = dict.fromkeys(attributes, kwargs.get('start', 0))
    for it in iterable:
        for attr in attributes:
            sums[attr] += getattr(it, attr)
    return sums

counts = multisum(someList, 'acounter', 'bcounter')
# {'bcounter': 45, 'acounter': 45}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative (which may not be faster) is to overload the addition operator for your class:

```
class Some(object):
  def __init__(self, acounter, bcounter):
    self.acounter = acounter
    self.bcounter = bcounter

  def __add__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
      return Some(self.acounter+other.acounter, self.bcounter+other.bcounter)
    elif isinstance(other, int):
      return self
    else:
      raise TypeError("useful message")

  __radd__ = __add__

somelist = [Some(x, x) for x in range(10)]

combined = sum(somelist)
print combined.acounter
print combined.bcounter
```

This way `sum` returns a `Some` object.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that this is really faster, but you can do it like thus:

First define `padd` (for "pair add") via:

```
def padd(p1,p2): 
    return (p1[0]+p2[0],p1[1]+p2[1])
```

For example, `padd((1,4), (5,10)) = (6,14)`

Then use `reduce`:

```
atotal, btotal = reduce(padd, ((x.acounter,x.bcounter) for x in someList))
```

in Python 3 you need to import `reduce` from `functools` but IIRC it can be used directly in Python 2.

On edit: For more than 2 attributes you can replace `padd` by `vadd` ("vector add") which can handle tuples of arbitrary dimensions:

```
def vadd(v1,v2):
    return tuple(x+y for x,y in zip(v1,v2))
```

For just 2 attributes it is probably more efficient to hard-wire in the dimension since there is less function-call overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line to accumulate all of the attributes that you wish to sum.

```
>>> A = ((s.acounter,s.bcounter) for s in someList)
```

Then use this trick from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19343/47078 to make separate lists of each attribute by themselves.

```
>>> [sum(x) for x in zip(*A)]
[45, 45]
```

You can obviously combine the lines, but I thought breaking it apart would be easier to follow here.

And based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22115957/47078), you can make it much more readable by defining an `unzip(iterable)` method.

```
def unzip(iterable):
    return zip(*iterable)
[sum(x) for x in unzip((s.acounter,s.bcounter) for s in someList)]
```