# Python: why is zip(*) used instead of unzip()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Given the [zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) why is **zip(*)** used to unzip instead of some function named **unzip()**?  For example [Transpose/Unzip Function (inverse of zip)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/a-transpose-unzip-function-in-python-inverse-of-zip) shows how to unzip a list.

```
>>> zip(*[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

How is that more:

- Beautiful than ugly
- Explicit than implicit
- Simple than complex
- Readable
- etc.

then

```
>>> unzip([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])
```

?

What am I missing here?

Comment: If this is not an upvotable question, how can it be improved?

Comment: This is `*`: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: As for the rest, *"there should be __one__ obvious way to do it."* Since `zip(*)` *can* do it and `*` is a very commonly used operator, why *should* there be an `unzip` to do the same thing?

Comment: By doing `zip(*[...])`, you're not unzipping. You're still zipping. That's what you're missing.

Comment: I realize this is a noob question.  I am looking to understand.   Are the python zen principles listed in order of priority?  Is your answer that using * to unpack the argument list makes unzip more widely versatile while at the same time providing only one way to do it?

Comment: What would `unzip` do? It would do exactly the same as `zip`, but accept its arguments as a list instead of as separate arguments. Sounds extremely redundant to me when that difference is already generalised in the `*` operator.

Comment: @ Vincent Savard - I'd mark that as the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not actually unzipping when you do `zip(*your_list)`. You're still zipping.

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) is a function that can take as many arguments as you want. In your case, you essentially have four different sequences that you want to zip: `('a', 1)`, `('b', 2)`, `('c', 3)` and `('d', 4)`. Thus, you want to call `zip` like this:

```
>>> zip(('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4))
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

But your sequences aren't in separate variables, you just have a list which contains them all. This is where the [`*` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) comes in. This operator *unpacks* the list in a way that each element of your list becomes an argument to the function.

This means that when you do this:

```
your_list = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
zip(*your_list)
```

Python calls `zip` which each element of your list as an argument, like this:

```
zip(('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4))
```

This is why an `unzip` function isn't necessary: Unzipping is just another kind of zip, and is easily achievable with just the `zip` function and the `*` operator.