# How should I convert a list of tuples into separate strings?

Tags: python

```
import obd
connection = obd.OBD()
r = connection.query(obd.commands.GET_DTC)
print(r.value)


example output:
[
  ("P0030", "HO2S Heater Control Circuit"),
  ("P1367", "Unknown error code")
]
```

I would like to store/access the second value in each outputted item (e.g. "HO2S Heater Control Circuit") as its own variable. Do I need to decode this output as a list or tuple or both?

Comment: What do you mean, "as its own variable"? Do you want to flatten the `list`? Or are you asking how to access nested items? Or do you just need mutable containers? Please be more specific.

Comment: Something like: `first, second = r.value[0]`?

Answer (score 1):

From [the page where this code seems to be from](http://python-obd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Commands/#mode-03):

> The value field of the response object will contain a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the DTC, and a string description of that DTC (if available).

So if `r = connection.query(obd.commands.GET_DTC)`, then `r.value` is a "list of tuples".  You can use the [zip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function (as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/a-transpose-unzip-function-in-python-inverse-of-zip)) to transpose the structure with `zip(*r.value)` which gives

```
    [('P0030', 'P1367'), ('HO2S Heater Control Circuit', 'Unknown error code')]
```

You just want the second element of this list, so

```
    zip(*r.value)[1]
```

gives you the tuple

```
    ('HO2S Heater Control Circuit', 'Unknown error code')
```

You could then use this as you wish.  Notice that this gives you *all* of the "second values in each outputted item".  You could iterate through all them (and, say print each one) with:

```
    for description in zip(*r.value)[1]:
        print description
```

It may be a good idea to assign `zip(*r.value)[1]` to a variable if you want to use it more than once.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use each second element you can unpack the tuples in a for loop:

```
for _, var in r.value:
    # use var
```

i.e:

```
In [4]: l = [                                                                                           
  ("P0030", "HO2S Heater Control Circuit"),
  ("P1367", "Unknown error code")
]

In [5]: for _, var in l:
          print(var)
   ...:     
HO2S Heater Control Circuit
Unknown error code
```

If you wanted them all for some reason could also use a list comp with the logic above or `operator.itemgetter`:

```
In [7]: list(map(itemgetter(1), l))
Out[7]: ['HO2S Heater Control Circuit', 'Unknown error code']

In [8]: from operator import itemgetter

In [9]: list(map(itemgetter(1), l))
Out[9]: ['HO2S Heater Control Circuit', 'Unknown error code']
```

You could also use `itemgetter(-1)` to get the last elements.

Comment: This is much simpler than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could "unpack" a tuple. So, from your example, `r.value[0]` is the tuple `("P0030", "HO2S Heater Control Circuit")` Then,

```
id, desc = r.value[0]
```

would unpack the tuple, r.value[0] into varaiables `id` and `desc` so that `P0030` is stored in `id` and `HO2S Heater Control Circuit` is stored in `desc`