# Naming dictionaries arbitrarily

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have     `list=[gender,employment type]` and i wanted to create a dictionary named `gender` and another dictionary named `employment type`. Can i name my dictionaries something as follows:

```
> list[0] = {key1: value}
> list[1] = {key2: value}
```

I wanted to name my dictionary arbitrarily depending on certain input.Is it possible to declare a dictionary using a string value from a list?

Comment: Did you mean `{key1: value}`?

Comment: yup, there, edited

Comment: Can you clarify what you want?  What you have written is legal, but perhaps it is not what you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into a combination of [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate). I've linked to the 2.x docs because of your tag, but I believe the functions are almost identical in 3.x.

Using a map:

```
>>> list=["gender", "employment type"]
>>> mapped=map(lambda x: {"key":x})
[{'key': 'gender'}, {'key': 'employment type'}]
```

with enumerate:

```
>>> list=["gender", "employment type"]
>>> map(lambda (i, x): {"key"+str(i):x}, enumerate(list))
[{'key0': 'gender'}, {'key1': 'employment type'}]
```

Given more deeply-nested structures — something like `list=[[gender], [employment type]]` — you can define a more intricate function as your mapper.

Alternatively, if you are looking at an array of `[gender, employment type]` tuples (something that more closely resembles `[(gender, employment type)]`) — you may want to look into "unzipping" the data. See the SO question: [A Transpose/Unzip Function in Python (inverse of zip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/a-transpose-unzip-function-in-python-inverse-of-zip).