# Reshape tuple array into two 1-D arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to reshape tuple array:

```
x = [(1,2), (5,4), (3,6)]
```

into two arrays: [1, 5, 3] and [2, 4, 6] in one line

This is working:

```
a = [x[0] for x in X]
b = [x[1] for x in X]
```

But this is not working:

```
(a, b) = [(x[0], x[1]) for x in X]
```

How can I do it in one line?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/transpose-unzip-function-inverse-of-zip Not sure if a direct duplicate...

Comment: That's definitely the answer. I think it's fine not to mark this as a duplicate, although an argument could certainly be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with zip:

```
a, b = zip(*x)
```