# convert unicode to two separate list in python

Tags: python, list

I have this unicode string .

```
u"[(2102, 'a'), (1882, 'b'), (1304, 'c'), (577, 'd'), (470, 'e')]"

<type 'unicode'>
```

how can i convert it to two separate list

Comment: Confusing because you show a list and then you say ` <type 'unicode'>. You must not be using a full example

Comment: Please specify python version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you showed is a list, but you said you had a string. So assuming you really do have a string, you can use `eval()` to turn it into a list and then do an [inverse `zip()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/transpose-unzip-function-inverse-of-zip) to get your values into two tuples (which can be easily converted into lists):

```
s = u"[(2102, 'a'), (1882, 'b'), (1304, 'c'), (577, 'd'), (470, 'e')]"
type(s)
#<type 'unicode'>
l1, l2 = zip(*(eval(s)))
print(l1)
#(2102, 1882, 1304, 577, 470)
print(l2)
#('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use two list comprehensions:

```
ex = [(2102, 'a'), (1882, 'b'), (1304, 'c'), (577, 'd'), (470, 'e')]
list1 = [x[0] for x in ex]
list2 = [x[1] for x in ex]
```

Comment: This is the output i'm getting when printing first list.,
[u'[', u'(', u'2', u'1', u'0', u'2', u',', u' ', u"'", u'a'..................

Comment: if you run the above example I provided it should return two lists as you asking, but it seems you're example above wasn't correctly entered and should been shown as `u"[(2102, 'a'), (1882, 'b'), (1304, 'c'), (577, 'd'), (470, 'e')]"` as in the response from @pault below, and thus that answer would be the right way of doing what you desire.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try

```
unicode_list =[(2102, 'a'), (1882, 'b'), (1304, 'c'), (577, 'd'), (470, 'e')]
map(list,zip(*unicode_list))
```

where zip() in conjunction with the * operator can be used to unzip a list.