# Weird plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot a demand profile for heating energy for a specific building with *Python* and *matplotlib*.
But instead of being a single line it looks like this:

[image]

Did anyone ever had plotting results like this?
Or does anyone have an idea whats going on here?

The corresponding code fragment is:

```
for b in list_of_buildings:

    print(b.label, b.Q_Heiz_a, b.Q_Heiz_TT, len(b.lp.heating_list))

    heating_datalist=[]
    for d in range(timesteps):
        b.lp.heating_list[d] = b.lp.heating_list[d]*b.Q_Heiz_TT     
        heating_datalist.append((d, b.lp.heating_list[d]))

        xs_heat = [x[0] for x in heating_datalist]
        ys_heat = [x[1] for x in heating_datalist]
        pyplot.plot(xs_heat, ys_heat, lw=0.5)              

pyplot.title(TT)

#get legend entries from list_of_buildings
list_of_entries = []
for b in list_of_buildings:
    list_of_entries.append(b.label)
pyplot.legend(list_of_entries)          
pyplot.xlabel("[min]")
pyplot.ylabel("[kWh]")
```

Additional info:

- `timesteps` is a list like [0.00, 0.01, 0.02, ... , 23.59] - the minutes of the day (24*60 values)
- `b.lp.heating_list` is a list containing some float values
- `b.Q_Heiz_TT` is a constant

Comment: Probably an issue with your data / data treatment. Add the data if you want help.

Comment: You plot `xs_heat`/`ys_heat` for each `d in range(timesteps)`. If `timesteps` is large, then you will have many lines on your plot. With the current information, we can't do much to help you. Please provide a simple example that reproduces the problem, or provide details of the shape/contents of `timesteps`, `b.lp.heating_list`, etc.

Comment: I added some info. The data is there. I double checked that.

Comment: @Tybald FYI: if you don't notify somebody with the @ mention, then he/she doesn't get an alert. I just happened to have revisited this page, otherwise I would not have known that you posted an update.

Comment: Looks a lot like a zooming problem to me. If you _zoom horizontally_, what do you see?

Comment: Or else, it is the way you are plotting. I notice that you call `plot` _once for each timestep_, while I would expect you to call `plot` once _per building`. The later would mean plotting "consumption vs time" for each building. Was that your intention?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information, I have created a minimal example that should reproduce your problem (if not, you may have not explained the problem/parameters in sufficient detail). I'd urge you to create such an example yourself next time, as your question is likely to get ignored without it. The example looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 24*60
Q_Heiz_TT = 0.5
lp_heating_list = np.random.rand(N)
lp_heating_list = lp_heating_list*Q_Heiz_TT

heating_datalist = []

for d in range(N):
    heating_datalist.append((d, lp_heating_list[d]))
    xs_heat = [x[0] for x in heating_datalist]
    ys_heat = [x[1] for x in heating_datalist]
    plt.plot(xs_heat, ys_heat)

plt.show()
```

What is going in in here? For each `d in range(N)` (with `N = 24*60`, i.e. each minute of the day), you plot all values **up to and including** `lp_heating_list[d]` versus `d`. This is because `heating_datalist`, is appended with the current value of `d` and corresponding value in `lp_heating_list`. What you get is 24x60=1440 lines that partially overlap one another. Depending on how your backend is handling things, it may be very slow and start to look messy.

A much better approach would be to simply use

```
plt.plot(range(timesteps), lp_heating_list)
plt.show()
```

Which plots only one line, instead of 1440 of them.

Comment: The problem is indeed the plot itself, not the data. 'plt.plot(timesteps, lp_heating_list)'  sounds good and I tried it but I get: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (1440,)  ... =/

Comment: My bad, plot `range(timesteps)`, not just `timesteps`

Comment: It is MUCH faster now, but it still looks like one big blob. I'm beginning to believe this is due to the plot type with lines. I'll try it with dots and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is an indentation problem in your code.

Try this:

```
heating_datalist=[]
for d in range(timesteps):
    b.lp.heating_list[d] = b.lp.heating_list[d]*b.Q_Heiz_TT     
    heating_datalist.append((d, b.lp.heating_list[d]))

xs_heat = [x[0] for x in heating_datalist]  # <<<<<<<<
ys_heat = [x[1] for x in heating_datalist]  # <<<<<<<<
pyplot.plot(xs_heat, ys_heat, lw=0.5)       # <<<<<<<<
```

That way you'll plot only one line per building, which is probably what you want.

Besides, you can use `zip` to generate x values and y values like this:

```
xs_heat, ys_heat = zip(*heating_datalist)
```

This works because [`zip` is it's own inverse!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19343/401828)

Comment: It's true, `zip(*...)` is elegant and short but also way less intuitional I guess. Nevertheless I came to the conclusion that there are just too many datapoints to plot  them the way I did.