# Find minimum and maximum value at each index of a dictionary of lists

Tags: python

I have a dictionary having following structure

```
{key1: [1,2,3,4,5], key2: [2,0,4,5,6]}
```

I need to find maximum and minimum value of each index of the value list, so at index 0, we compare `1 and 2` and choose `2` as the maximum, and `1` as the minimum, etc.

Expected output for my example:

```
min = [1,0,3,4,5]
max = [2,2,4,5,6]
```

I cannot use operator as I am not allowed to import it. I tried to used following approach but failed (syntax error). Also I won't iterate through the value set as is not the elegant way (IMO).

```
maxVal = max(myDictionary.items(), key=(lambda k: myDictionary[k]))
```

gives me

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Can you correct it or suggest any alternative approach.

Comment: Can you show what you want the output to look like?

Comment: @dfundako added expected output

Comment: @student Please run your code and confirm it looks like the expected output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use **`zip`** with **`min`** and **`max`**:

```
dct = {'key1': [1,2,3,4,5], 'key2': [2,0,4,5,6]}

[min(i) for i in zip(*dct.values())]
[max(i) for i in zip(*dct.values())]
```

Output:

```
[1, 0, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 2, 4, 5, 6]
```

If you want to get really fancy, you can also use the transpose trick of `zip` twice to turn this into a one-liner:

```
min_list, max_list = map(list, zip(*[(min(i), max(i)) for i in zip(*dct.values())]))

min_list
[1, 0, 3, 4, 5]

max_list
[2, 2, 4, 5, 6]
```

**This fancy method behaves badly with empty lists**

For example:

```
dct = {1: [], 2: []}
```

Will break this method.  In fact, pretty much all the ways to break this method involve using an empty list somewhere.

---

I've mentioned the **`zip`** transpose trick twice, so here is why it is necessary here:

If you simply use **`list(zip(dct.values()))`**, you will get the following output:

```
[([2, 0, 4, 5, 6],), ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],)]
```

This is not the desired result, we want a pairwise comparison of every element at each index of our sublists.  However we can leverage the fact that [`zip` is its own tranpose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19343/3483203) when you use the `*` operator.

So using **`list(zip(*dct.values()))`** provides us with our desired pairwise grouping for comparison:

```
[(2, 1), (0, 2), (4, 3), (5, 4), (6, 5)]
```