# Sum attributes of duplicate coordinates in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am going through my coordinates data and I see some duplicate coordinates with different parameters due to certain preprocessing. I want to be able to merge the attributes corresponding to the matched coordinates and get the simplified results. To clarify what I mean here is an example:

```
X = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0]
Y = [8.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0]
A = [13, 16, 20, 8]
```

The above data is read as follows: point (1.0, 8.0) has a value of 13 and (2.0, 3.0) has a value of 16. Notice that the second point and fourth point have the same coordinates but different attribute values. I want to be able to remove the duplicates from the lists of coordinates and sum the attributes so the results would be new lists:

```
New_X = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
New_Y = [8.0, 3.0, 4.0]
New_A = [13, 24, 20]
```

24 is the sum of 16 and 8 from the second and fourth points with the same coordinates, therefore one point is kept and the values are summed.

I am not sure how to do this, I thought of using nested for loops of zips of the coordinates but I am not sure how to formulate it to sum the attributes.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I think that maintaining 3 lists is a bit awkward. Something like:

```
D = dict()
for x,y,a in zip(X,Y,A):
    D[(x,y)] = D.get((x,y),0) + a
```

would put everything together in one place.

If you'd prefer to decompose it back into 3 lists:

```
for (x,y),a in D.items():
    newX.append(x)
    newY.append(y)
    newA.append(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option here is to use `itertools.groupby`. But since this only groups consecutive keys, you'll have to first sort your coordinates.

First we can `zip` them together to create tuples of the form `(x, y, a)`. Then sort these by the `(x, y)` coordinates:

```
sc = sorted(zip(X, Y, A), key=lambda P: (P[0], P[1]))  # sorted coordinates
print(sc)
#[(1.0, 8.0, 13), (2.0, 3.0, 16), (2.0, 3.0, 8), (3.0, 4.0, 20)]
```

Now we can `groupby` the coordinates and sum the values:

```
from itertools import groupby
print([(*a, sum(c[2] for c in b)) for a, b in groupby(sc, key=lambda P: (P[0], P[1]))])
#[(1.0, 8.0, 13), (2.0, 3.0, 24), (3.0, 4.0, 20)]
```

And since [`zip` is its own inverse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19343/5858851), you can get `New_X`, `New_Y`, and `New_A` via:

```
New_X, New_Y, New_A = zip(
    *((*a, sum(c[2] for c in b)) for a, b in groupby(sc, key=lambda P: (P[0], P[1])))
)
print(New_X)
print(New_Y)
print(New_A)
#(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
#(8.0, 3.0, 4.0)
#(13, 24, 20)
```

Of course, you can do this all in one line but I broke it up into pieces so that it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

you could put the `(x,y)` coords in a dictionary:

```
dict = {}
for i in range(len(X)) # len(X) = len(Y)
    if (X[i], Y[i]) not in dict.keys():
        dict[(X[i], Y[i])] = A[i]
    else:
       dict[(X[i], Y[i])] += A[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use a dictionary

```
d = {}

for i in range(len(X)):
    tup = (X[i], Y[i])
    if tup in d:
        d[tup] += A[i]
    else:
        d[tup] = A[i]

New_X = []
New_Y = []
New_A = [] 
for key in d.keys():
    New_X.append(key[0])
    New_Y.append(key[1])
    New_A.append(d[key])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this list comprehension:

```
y,x,a=zip(*[e for c,e in enumerate(zip(Y,X,A)) if not e[0:1] in [x[0:1] for x in zip(X,Y,A)][c:]])
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dict` seems like a more appropriate data structure here. This will build one.

```
from collections import Counter

D = sum((Counter({(x, y): a}) for x, y, a in zip(X, Y, A)), Counter())
print(D)
#Counter({(2.0, 3.0): 24, (3.0, 4.0): 20, (1.0, 8.0): 13})
```

You can unpack these back into separate lists using:

```
New_X, New_Y, New_A = map(list, zip(*[(x,y,a) for (x,y),a in D.items()]))
print(New_X)
print(New_Y)
print(New_A)
#[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
#[8.0, 3.0, 4.0]
#[13, 24, 20]
```

Comment: @pault While your edit is constructive, I'd prefer if you didn't edit my answer so substantially. Especially considering you have already answered the question yourself.

Comment: my apologies- I just wanted to show how to get the final result OP showed. Feel free to rollback if you wish and I can add that last part as a comment.