# Seprate List into two independent variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables, dataframe

I have a list which has two attributes and I want to seperate it into two independent variables in single new dataframe, for example:

```
dataframe = (var1, var2)
var1 = client, say, management, take
var2 = NN, VBP, NN, VB
```

My list now:

```
print(Grammer[:10])
[('client', 'NN'), ('say', 'VBP'), ('management', 'NN'), ('take', 'VB'), ('decission', 'NN'), ('submitted', 'VBN')]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpose/Unzip Function (inverse of zip)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/transpose-unzip-function-inverse-of-zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `zip` + unpacking:

```
lst = [('client', 'NN'), ('say', 'VBP'), ('management', 'NN'), ('take', 'VB'), ('decission', 'NN'), ('submitted', 'VBN')]

var1, var2 = zip(*lst)

print(var1)  # ('client', 'say', 'management', 'take', 'decission', 'submitted')                                                       
print(var2)  # ('NN', 'VBP', 'NN', 'VB', 'NN', 'VBN')
```

Comment: Returning error as  "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Comment: @ChetanJawale that's not because of the size of the list, it's because one of your tuples has more than 2 values.

Comment: Do you have a list containing tuples of two elements? It seems not.

Comment: @Austin Yes, my list contains tuples of two elements !  = ('client', 'NN'), ('say', 'VBP'), ('management', 'NN')

Comment: I mean some (not all) tuples have more than two elements. The error is thrown because it failed to unpack them. It expected two but found more. Because you didn't add details of that part, it's nearly impossible for us to guess you've a case like that.

Comment: It Worked..! ;) Thank You for your help..!

Comment: @blhsing, okay, Thank you :)