# how to plot histogram in matplotlib when data is in tuples?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot a histogram of the 5 most frequently occurring words in a list.  I've used the collections module's c.counter().most_common() to give me the following tuples:

```
[('you', 7706), ('i', 6570), ('we', 2733), ('my', 2718), ('he', 2369)]
```

How can I plot a histogram when the data is in the format ('word', frequency)?

The format that I am familiar with is:  ['you', 'you', 'you', ... , 'i', 'i', 'i', ... , etc.]

I know that I could multiply the string times the integer in each element to build a new list in the format I am familiar with to plot on the histogram but I feel like there has to be a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Unzip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19339/8881141) your list of tuples:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

a = [('you', 7706), ('i', 6570), ('we', 2733), ('my', 2718), ('he', 2369)]

plt.bar(*zip(*a))
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use matplotlib bar chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


items = [('you', 7706), ('i', 6570), ('we', 2733), ('my', 2718), ('he', 2369)]
y_pos = np.arange(len(items)) 
plt.bar(y_pos, [x[1] for x in items], align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, [x[0] for x in items])

plt.show()
```

With the result:
[image: Bar Chart]

Answer (score 1):

I prefer pandas for easy manipulation of data and plotting:

```
import pandas

freqs = [('you', 7706), ('i', 6570), ('we', 2733), ('my', 2718), ('he', 2369)]

# Create a DataFrame for the data, with names for the columns
freqdf = pandas.DataFrame(freqs, columns=['Word', 'Count']).set_index('Word')
freqdf.plot.barh()
```

Resulting plot:

[image: Bar plot]

Comment: Thank you but this was for an exercise in matplotlib unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extension of above solution using `Matplotlib` as well as `Seaborn`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

lst = [('you', 7706), ('i', 6570), ('we', 2733), ('my', 2718), ('he', 2369)]

val, cnt = (zip(*lst))
val, cnt = list(val), list(cnt)
val, cnt
# (['you', 'i', 'we', 'my', 'he'], [7706, 6570, 2733, 2718, 2369])

# using Matplotlib
length = len(cnt)
plt.bar(np.arange(length), cnt, label=True)
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(cnt)), val)
plt.show()
```

[image: matpl]

```
# using seaborn 
sns.barplot( val, cnt )
```

[image: sea]

Comment: Thank you, I would prefer seaborn but I had to use matplotlib for this particular exercise.