# Save deque into csv data frame

Tags: python, regex, deque, saving-data

I am working with tracking elements video using `opencv` (basically counting number of elements after hsv thresholding). I have a `deque` buffer to store centroid positions. I chose a limited buffer of 64 (~2 seconds on 30 fps, could be longer). My goal is to save the data into `.csv` file in such a format that I can readily use later (see below). Additionally, I am counting the number of detected regions. The format would be like

```
cX  cY  number
444 265   19
444 265   19
444 264   19
444 264   19
...
```

With `cX` being the centroid in X and `cY` the centroid in Y of the largest element, and the number of detected regions. Column naming is not the main goal although it would be nice.

For display purposes, I need to have the centroid as `tuple`. I make them grow frame by frame using `appendleft`:

```
center_points = deque(maxlen=64)
object_number = deque(maxlen=64)
iteration_counter = 1

    while True


        # read video frames..
        # do stuff...
        # get contours
            my_cnts = cv2.findContours(...)
        # get largest object
            c = max(my_cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
            ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
            M = cv2.moments(c)
            big_center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))
# count object number as int name it 'num'

center_points.appendleft(big_center)
object_number.appendleft(num)
```

Now, when the buffer is full, I want to save the data into file):

```
# Convert to array to save
    # Wait until the iteration number is divisible by the buffer length
    if(iteration_number % 64 == 0):
        print("Saving on iteration..." + str(iteration_number))
        array_to_save = np.array([center_points, object_number]).T


        with open(filename,'a') as outfile:
            np.savetxt(outfile, array_to_save,
                       delimiter=',', fmt='%s')
# Add 1 to the counter
    iteration_number = iteration_number + 1
```

### Problem

The code above works and writes something that looks like this:

```
(444 265) 19
(444 265) 19
(444 264) 19
(444 263) 19
```

I would like to do something like `np.array(center_points)` and bind that to `object_number`. I have had trouble with dimensions (e.g, (64,2) and (64) not being compatible). I have tried `np.append` and `np.stack` but can't find the correct way of formatting the data.

Else, I could keep the code as is but I would like to somehow get rid of the parenthesis on columns 1 and 2 and save that object instead (have tried regular expressions on `array_to_save` without success). All three columns should be numeric or saved as string but easily retrieved as numeric later in reading.

### Update

Based on comments I tried

```
array_to_save = np.concatenate([np.array(center_points), object_number[:, None]])
    TypeError: sequence index must be integer, not 'tuple'
```

I also tried

```
array_to_save = np.concatenate([np.array(center_points), np.array(object_number)[:, None]])
    ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Comment: You can use `np.concatenate(x, y[:, None])`, i.e. add extra column dimension to have `(64, 2)` and `(64, 1)`, then you can concatenate.

Comment: @a_guest This does not work am I running correctly?  `array_to_save = np.concatenate(np.array(center_points), object_number[:, None])
TypeError: sequence index must be integer, not 'tuple'`

Comment: You need to enclose the arguments in an additional sequence, i.e. `np.concatenate([np.array(center_points), object_number[:, None]])`.

Comment: @a_guest Please see update.

Comment: Well it looks like `object_number` does not have as many items as `center_points`. Anyway the general rule is that along the common axis, in our case this is the `0-th` axis, the two arrays to be concatenated need to have the same length. You can check the length in each dimension by `.shape`. I.e. do `c = np.array(center_points); o = np.array(object_number)[:, None]` and then check `c.shape` and `o.shape`. Since `shape[0]` is the common axis it needs to be the same number. For example `c.shape == (60, 2); o.shape == (60, 1)` would be fine and `c.shape == (60, 2); o.shape == (58, 1)` is not.

Comment: this ended up working, you should post an answer to the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) the arrays along the column dimension in order to create a `(X, 3)` array out of the `(X, 2)` and `(X,)` array. In order to be ready for concatenation all the arrays need to have the same number of dimensions and hence you need to add an extra dimension to the flat array `object_number`: `(X,) -> (X, 1)`. This can by done via `object_number[:, np.newaxis]` or `object_number[:, None]`. The complete solution then is:

```
np.concatenate([np.array(center_points),
                np.array(object_number)[:, None]], axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of your difficulty, I think, is that `np.savetxt()` does not work well with tuples held in numpy arrays. I've developed some test code that I think replicates the key aspects of your problem and provides solutions to them:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import deque

# Create test data
center_points = deque(maxlen=64)
number = deque(maxlen=64)
for i in range(10):
    big_center = (i*3,i*100)
    center_points.appendleft(big_center)
    number.appendleft(19)

# Write the test data

array_to_save = np.array([center_points,number]).T
print (array_to_save)
with open("test.txt","w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n".join([" ".join([str(a[0]),str(a[1]),str(b)]) for a,b in
        array_to_save]))

# Re-read the test data
center_points2 = deque(maxlen=64)
number2 = deque(maxlen=64)

with open("test.txt","r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        x = [int(xx) for xx in line.split()]
        center_points2.append((x[0],x[1]))
        number2.append(x[2])
    new_array = np.array([center_points2,number2]).T

print (new_array)
```

When run, this code outputs the following, showing that the original `array_to_save` is identical to the `new_array` that has been read back in:

```
[[(27, 900) 19]
 [(24, 800) 19]
 [(21, 700) 19]
 [(18, 600) 19]
 [(15, 500) 19]
 [(12, 400) 19]
 [(9, 300) 19]
 [(6, 200) 19]
 [(3, 100) 19]
 [(0, 0) 19]]
[[(27, 900) 19]
 [(24, 800) 19]
 [(21, 700) 19]
 [(18, 600) 19]
 [(15, 500) 19]
 [(12, 400) 19]
 [(9, 300) 19]
 [(6, 200) 19]
 [(3, 100) 19]
 [(0, 0) 19]]
```

The file `test.txt` is as follows:

```
27 900 19
24 800 19
21 700 19
18 600 19
15 500 19
12 400 19
9 300 19
6 200 19
3 100 19
0 0 19
```

The file reading and writing code in this version is a little more complicated than just calling `np.savetxt()` but it handles the tuples explicitly.

#### Update

Alternatively, if you preferred to do all the manipulation in the `numpy` arrays, you could use:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import deque

# Create test data
center_points = deque(maxlen=64)
number = deque(maxlen=64)
for i in range(10):
    big_center = (i*3,i*100)
    center_points.appendleft(big_center)
    number.appendleft(19)

print (center_points)
print (number)

# Write the test data

x, y = zip(*center_points)
array_to_save = np.array([x,y,number]).T
print (array_to_save)
np.savetxt("test.txt", array_to_save, fmt="%d")

# Re-read the test data
new_array = np.loadtxt("test.txt", dtype=int)
print (new_array)

center_points2 = deque(zip(new_array.T[0],new_array.T[1]),maxlen=64)
number2 = deque(new_array.T[2],maxlen=64)
print (center_points2)
print (number2)
```

This uses the approach described in [Transpose/Unzip Function (inverse of zip)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/transpose-unzip-function-inverse-of-zip) to separate the two elements of each tuple into two lists that are then included with the `number` list into a single `numpy` array that can be saved with `savetxt()` and re-loaded with `loadtxt()`.

The `print()` calls are just to illustrate that the data that the program finishes with is exactly the same as the data that it started with. They produce the following output:

```
deque([(27, 900), (24, 800), (21, 700), (18, 600), (15, 500), (12, 400), (9, 300), (6, 200), (3, 100), (0, 0)], maxlen=64)
deque([19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19], maxlen=64)
[[ 27 900  19]
 [ 24 800  19]
 [ 21 700  19]
 [ 18 600  19]
 [ 15 500  19]
 [ 12 400  19]
 [  9 300  19]
 [  6 200  19]
 [  3 100  19]
 [  0   0  19]]
[[ 27 900  19]
 [ 24 800  19]
 [ 21 700  19]
 [ 18 600  19]
 [ 15 500  19]
 [ 12 400  19]
 [  9 300  19]
 [  6 200  19]
 [  3 100  19]
 [  0   0  19]]
deque([(27, 900), (24, 800), (21, 700), (18, 600), (15, 500), (12, 400), (9, 300), (6, 200), (3, 100), (0, 0)], maxlen=64)
deque([19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19], maxlen=64)
```

Comment: This solution could potentially work, although I would prefer dealing with the data before saving and having a way to deal with tuples going into the np.array, transforming them either before or after they were concatenated. Any ideas on that?