# why itertools.zip_longest(*indexes_batch) return an transpose result against itertools.zip_longest(indexes_batch)

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor like this

```
indexes_batch  
[[28, 633, 1076, 332, 270, 123, 28, 6, 2],
 [47, 171, 120, 12, 261, 58, 1103, 6, 2],
 [1473, 3646, 7, 260, 4, 4, 4, 2],
 [531, 42, 55, 127, 654, 4, 2],
 [639, 6, 2]]
```

when I use `list(itertools.zip_longest(*indexes_batch, fillvalue=0))` I get
`[(28, 47, 1473, 531, 639),
 (633, 171, 3646, 42, 6),
 (1076, 120, 7, 55, 2),
 (332, 12, 260, 127, 0),
 (270, 261, 4, 654, 0),
 (123, 58, 4, 4, 0),
 (28, 1103, 4, 2, 0),
 (6, 6, 2, 0, 0),
 (2, 2, 0, 0, 0)]`

and use `list(itertools.zip_longest(indexes_batch, fillvalue=0))`,I get

```
[([28, 633, 1076, 332, 270, 123, 28, 6, 2],),
 ([47, 171, 120, 12, 261, 58, 1103, 6, 2],),
 ([1473, 3646, 7, 260, 4, 4, 4, 2],),
 ([531, 42, 55, 127, 654, 4, 2],),
 ([639, 6, 2],)]
```

so waht I confused about is what is the function of `*` ,and why can `*` result a Transposed matrix

Comment: because by unpacking you are matching every sublist indexes together, if not using `*` it it just packing the sublists into a tuple because there is not other elements to match in the same index.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/transpose-unzip-function-inverse-of-zip for an explanation.