# can I get multiple return values from inline for?

Tags: python

Is it possible to get multiple return values from inline for?
e.g.,:

```
a,b=[(1,2) for _ in range(3)]
```

such that:

```
a=[1,1,1]
b=[2,2,2]
```

Comment: I would use `a, b = [1] * 3, [2] * 3` or `a, b = ([i] * 3 for i in (1, 2))` *(if you want to apply generator)*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transpose/Unzip Function (inverse of zip)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/transpose-unzip-function-inverse-of-zip)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip) function

```
>>> a, b = zip(*[(1,2) for _ in range(3)])
>>> a
(1, 1, 1)
>>> b
(2, 2, 2)
```

or also

```
>>> a, b = [1]*3, [2]*3
>>> a
[1, 1, 1]
>>> b
[2, 2, 2]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `zip` built-in can be kind of "abused" to yield this kind of output:

```py
In [203]: a, b = zip(*((1,2) for _ in range(3)))                                                                       

In [204]: a                                                                                                            
Out[204]: (1, 1, 1)

In [205]: b                                                                                                            
Out[205]: (2, 2, 2)
```