# How do I get only the first number without brackets in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list `l1` this is structured according to the scheme `[(number1, number2), ... (number1n, number2n]`. I would like to always only want the very first number and remove the brackets. How do I do that?

```
l1 = [(285, 1.0000001), (3614, 0.93460923), (671, 0.78742), (1351, 0.72903967), (3883, 0.6139718)]
l2 = [285, 3614, 671, 1351, 3883]
```

Comment: [a for a,b in l1]

Comment: If you had just `(number1, number2)`, would you know how to get `number1` out of that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transpose/Unzip Function (inverse of zip)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/transpose-unzip-function-inverse-of-zip)

Comment: Top! Quickly and correctly, thank you very much. Have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
l1 = [(285, 1.0000001), (3614, 0.93460923), (671, 0.78742), (1351, 0.72903967), (3883, 0.6139718)]


l2 = [i[0] for i in l1]
```

or

```
l2 = [i for i,j in l1]
```

Also you can do it with `zip`.

```
l2 = list(zip(*l1))[0]
```

Using `map`:

```
l2 = list(map(lambda x:x[0], l1))
```