# simplify code using an inverse dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, simplify

Consider some mapping `my_map` that defines the order of some keys, and some dictionary `my_dict` that maps the same keys into some values:

```
my_map = {'x' : 2, 'y' : 0, 'z' : 1}
my_dict = {'x' : 'foo', 'z' : 'bar', 'y' : 'baz'}
```

I want to get an ordered list of the values of `my_dict` using the order defined by `my_map`. My best approach of getting there is:

```
inv_map = {v: k for k, v in my_map.items()}
ordered_list = [my_dict[k] for k in [inv_map[d] for d in range(len(my_map))]]
```

Is there a less clunky way of doing the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use sorted very efficiently here using `dict.get`:

```
[my_dict[k] for k in sorted(my_map, key=my_map.get)]
```

In action:

```
>>> my_map = {'x' : 2, 'y' : 0, 'z' : 1}
>>> my_dict = {'x' : 'foo', 'z' : 'bar', 'y' : 'baz'}
>>> [my_dict[k] for k in sorted(my_map, key=my_map.get)]
['baz', 'bar', 'foo']
```

Comment: do you think, that map will be work faster than list comprehension?

Comment: I believe it would be I can test and let you know.

Comment: as I read and tried some years ago, comprehension is faster :) we can try both and then write here our results

Comment: No you're right I thought the fact that I was using a single function it'd be faster. I edited my answer @dukkee

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `sorted` function to order your map by value and then convert it:

```py
[my_dict[k] for k in sorted(my_map, key=lambda key: my_map[key])]
```

Somewhat cleaner at least!

Let's make sure that it works:

```
>>> my_map = {'x' : 2, 'y' : 0, 'z' : 1}
>>> my_dict = {'x' : 'foo', 'z' : 'bar', 'y' : 'baz'}
>>> [my_dict[k] for k in sorted(my_map, key=lambda key: my_map[key])]
['baz', 'bar', 'foo']
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the situation you can init final list and pass items to the needed positions

```
result = [None] * len(my_dict)

for k, v in my_dict.items():
    result[my_map[k]] = v
```

Answer (score 1):

Still another variation (I think it's different from already presented solutions):

```
[x[1] for x in sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda elem: my_map[elem[0]])]
```

Testing code:

```
my_map = {'x' : 2, 'y' : 0, 'z' : 1}
my_dict = {'x' : 'foo', 'z' : 'bar', 'y' : 'baz'}

print(my_dict.items())

sorted_result=[x[1] for x in sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda elem: my_map[elem[0]])]

print(sorted_result)
```

Or a bit differently:

```
sorted_result=list(zip(*sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda elem: my_map[elem[0]])))[1]
```

> I wanted to use `zip()` to split a list of tuples into 2 lists, but in Python 3 `zip()` returns *iterator* (not a *list*), so (as suggested in [Transpose/Unzip Function (inverse of zip)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/transpose-unzip-function-inverse-of-zip)) I wrapped it in `list()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sorted` with the values from `my_dict` and a key function that sorts them with the values from `my_map`

```py
ordered_list = sorted(my_dict.values(), key=lambda s:my_map[{v: k for k, v in my_dict.items()}[s]])
```

if it's sorted the wrong way you can use `reverse=True`

Comment: while the code correctly returns ['baz', 'bar', 'foo'] in the example here, it doesn't seem to work in general

Comment: the only way I can find for it not to work is if a key in `my_dict` isn't in `my_map`

Comment: here's an example ```my_map = {'x' : 2, 'y' : 0, 'z' : 1}``` and ```my_dict = {'x' : 100, 'y' : 100, 'z' : 10}```. The correct order is ```[100, 10, 100]```, but this code gives ```[100, 100, 10]```. I couldn't fully figure out why it fails in this example. Maybe because the values of ```my_dict``` are numeric here?

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that it switches the keys/values of `my_dict`, and because  `my_dict` has duplicate values, the new dict can't have duplicate keys

Comment: You are right, the same issue occurs for ```my_dict = {'x' : 'foo', 'y' : 'foo', 'z' : 'bar'}```