# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable in batch = Transition(*zip(*transitions))

Tags: python, zip, q-learning, dqn

There is an error in the line batch = Transition(*zip(*transitions)).
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

```
def optimize_model():
    if len(memory) < BATCH_SIZE:
            return
    transitions = memory.sample(BATCH_SIZE)
    # Transpose the batch (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19343/3343043 for
    # detailed explanation). This converts batch-array of Transitions
    # to Transition of batch-arrays.
        

    # Compute a mask of non-final states and concatenate the batch elements
    # (a final state would've been the one after which simulation ended)
    non_final_mask = torch.tensor(tuple(map(lambda s: s is not None,
                                              batch.next_state)), device=device, dtype=torch.uint8)
    non_final_next_states = torch.cat([s for s in batch.next_state 
                                                if s is not None])

    state_batch = torch.cat(batch.state)
    action_batch = torch.cat(batch.action)
    reward_batch = torch.cat(batch.reward)

    # Compute Q(s_t, a) - the model computes Q(s_t), then we select the
    # columns of actions taken. These are the actions which would've been taken
    # for each batch state according to policy_net
    state_action_values = policy_net(state_batch).gather(1, action_batch)
    # Compute V(s_{t+1}) for all next states.
    # Expected values of actions for non_final_next_states are computed based
    # on the "older" target_net; selecting their best reward with max(1)[0].
    # This is merged based on the mask, such that we'll have either the expected
    # state value or 0 in case the state was final.
    next_state_values = torch.zeros(BATCH_SIZE, device=device)
    next_state_values[non_final_mask] = target_net(non_final_next_states).max(1)[0].detach()
    # Compute the expected Q values
    expected_state_action_values = (next_state_values * GAMMA) + reward_batch
    # Compute Huber loss
    loss = F.smooth_l1_loss(state_action_values, expected_state_action_values.unsqueeze(1))
    # Optimize the model
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    for param in policy_net.parameters():
        param.grad.data.clamp_(-1, 1)
    optimizer.step()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\GDBot-master\GDBot.py", line 302, in 
<module>
    optimize_model()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\GDBot-master\GDBot.py", line 168, in 
optimize_model
    batch = Transition(*zip(*transitions))
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

This error appears spontaneously, sometimes it may not be at all.
I have absolutely no idea what the error is, thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: please translate to English, most users here speak English

Comment: Please provide the full traceback. The offending line is nowhere to be found.